# How do I persist state between re-creations of the same component?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a React application that fetches a list of clusters from a database and displays it in a grid view. Since, the list of clusters changes very rarily (maybe once a week), I don't want to fetch it every time the user visits `/clusters`.

I have tried to change `useState` to `useRef`, but in both cases `clusters` is `[]`, when the component is re-created (not re-rerendered?)

I'm not sure my terminology is correct, so please correct me, if I'm wrong.

What's the React way of solving this problem?

```
useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.
```

App.jsx:

```
...
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/clusters" element={<ClusterList />} />
  <Route path="/clusters/:id" element={<ClusterInfo />} />
  <Route path="/assets" element={<Assets />} />
</Routes>
...
```

ClusterList.jsx:

```
export const ClusterList = () => {
  const discoveryApi = useApi(discoveryApiRef);
  const authFetch = useAuthFetch();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [clusters, setClusters] = useState<Cluster[]>([]);

  const fetchClusters = useCallback(async (): Promise<Cluster[]> => {
    const url = await discoveryApi.getBaseUrl('containerplatform');
    const response = await authFetch(`${url}/clusters`);
    return await response.json();
  }, [discoveryApi, authFetch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const _clusters = await fetchClusters();
        setClusters(_clusters);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    })();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [fetchClusters]);
...
```

Comment: The general solution is to lift state up https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html.  A generic way of doing this is to have a `useState` in `App.jsx` which will remember the clusters.  You can still do the fetch in the child, but you can pass them back to the parent by a callback function passed into the child prop.  This is a common scenario and there are common solutions, such as redux https://react-redux.js.org/ and the redux toolkit rtkquery https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview which solves much of the fetching/is loading/caching logic for you.

Comment: @possum Thank you. When the user re-visits `/clusters`, `ClusterList` isn't just rendered, it's re-created, right? (or what's the right term?) The docs say that `useState`'s value persists between re-renders of the component. In the case of lifting state to `App.jsx`, isn't the `App` component re-created too, i.e. its `useState` value resets, when the user visits `/clusters`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on state variables to persist information, you will need to use localStorage or sessionStorage for storing cluster information, in you case using localStorage will suffice.

Example of using localStorage:-

```js
  const fetchClusters = useCallback(async (): Promise<Cluster[]> => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('clusters')){
      const url = await discoveryApi.getBaseUrl('containerplatform');
      const response = await authFetch(`${url}/clusters`);
      const clusters = await response.json();
      localStorage.setItem('clusters', JSON.stringify(clusters))
    }

    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('clusters'))
  }, [discoveryApi, authFetch]);
```